# React.Children.map vs children.map, what's the difference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In [React v16.2.0](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren), there is a new API call `React.Children`.

I am curious what's the different between `React.Children` and use `children` directly.

For example, if I want to manipulate the children content, I can do the trick in both methods. [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/4lxx4ynz70)

```
const Child = () => (
  <div>child</div>
)

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const template1 = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
      return React.cloneElement(child);
    });

    const template2 = this.props.children.map((child) => {
      return React.cloneElement(child);
    });
    return [template1, template2];
  }
}
```

And the result is the same.

Does anyone know what is the different?

Or what is the purpose for React team to release this API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, for your operations there is no real difference. However, `React.Children` provides utilities for dealing with `this.props.children`. For the use of `map` there was one comment in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) that I thought might be interesting:

> If children is a keyed fragment or array it will be traversed

So their implementation seems to be doing a little more than if your just used `Array.prototype.map`.

You can read on what other [functionality `React.Children` provides](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren), but it largely seems like they are providing convenience functions so you don't have to worry about traversing children who may have children and so on.

Comment: Your answer seems to be outdated now, it says "If children is a Fragment it will be treated as a single child and not traversed."

Answer (score 17):

The children of React component is a node which might be undefined or null. React.Children.map is a utility function to help you handle different cases.

[React.Children.map](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap)

> Invokes a function on every immediate child contained within children with this set to thisArg. If children is an array it will be traversed and the function will be called for each child in the array. If children is null or undefined, this method will return null or undefined rather than an array.

You should always use React.Children.map to traverse children in your app. Use children.map throws an error when children is not an array.

Answer (score 9):

Please take a look at this example to see the different

Paste this to console browser:

```
var children = null
chidren.map(i => {return i}) // => VM370:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
React.Children.map(children, i => {return i;}) // return null
```

Here is the result:

[image: result]

So React.Children.map will handle the case when children is null or undefined

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer.  However please don't post a link to other pages.  Show the difference in your own post, and give the explanation there

Comment: it's image not other pages, I cannot post inline image due to not enough contribute point.