# Render JSX inside ReactMarkDown

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, markdown, react-markdown

How to render JSX inside ReactMarkDown? I want to wrap my JSX elements inside `ReactMarkDown` component and achieve something like this,

```
  <ReactMarkdown>
    <Grid>
      {Some text}
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
      {Some text}
    </Grid>
 </ReactMarkdown>
```

What is the best possible approach for this rather than using `<ReactMarkdown>` multiple times inside each JSX element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [MDX](https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx), it lets you use JSX and markdown together.

For example:

```
<Grid>
  # heading
</Grid>
<Grid>
  *italic*
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to create a custom component.

This component example map through your children node, and wrap each child with `ReactMarkDown`.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap

```
const MarkdownPlus = ({ children }) => (        
    React.Children.map(children, child => (
       <ReactMarkdown>
              {React.cloneElement(child, {})}
       </ReactMarkdown>
    )))
);
```

And use it like this

```
 <MarkdownPlus>
    <Grid>
      {Some text}
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
      {Some text}
    </Grid>
 </MarkdownPlus>
```

[React.Children.map vs children.map, what's the different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291442/react-children-map-vs-children-map-whats-the-different)

Disclaimer: I'm not sure whether ReactMarkdown accepts `<Grid>` as child or not. If it accepts only plain text (markdown code) then the above code will not work. You will need to apply `<ReactMarkDown>` to each `<Grid>`.

Comment: I think <ReactMarkDown> only accepts plain text.